# Vagrant can't use the requested machine because it is locked

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine, homestead

I have tried to access my projects sites that I have set up on homestead, they were working all fine before, and I haven't been working on them for few weeks, but today when I have tried to access them I couldn't open the sites. I have tried to run vagrant ssh but I get this error:

```
  VM must be running to open SSH connection. Run `vagrant up`
  to start the virtual machine.
```

And when I try to do vagrant up, I get:

```
  Vagrant can't use the requested machine because it is locked! This
  means that another Vagrant process is currently reading or modifying
  the machine. Please wait for that Vagrant process to end and try
  again. Details about the machine are shown below:

  Name: default
  Provider: virtualbox
```

When I do:

```
 vagrant status 'idOfTheMachine'
```

I get:

```
vagrant status 'idOfTheMachine'
/Users/myName/Homestead/Vagrantfile:4: warning: already initialized constant VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION
/Users/myName/Homestead/Vagrantfile:4: warning: previous definition of VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION was here
Current machine states:

default                   poweroff (virtualbox)

The VM is powered off. To restart the VM, simply run `vagrant up`
```

When I have opened virtualbox, and tried to see the shared folders, I could see the shared folders in the terminal but not the projects inside of them. I have googled around about this issue, but can't find any solution to it. Should I destroy the homestead machine on the virtual box and make a new one, and if so, how to make that properly, so that I have the same projects on the new machine?

Comment: What does `vagrant status` say?

Comment: I have edited the question with vagrant status response

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have this problem as well, and while I don't understand how/why it happens, I did find that running

```
vagrant reload {boxid}
```

will usually bring up the box and allow me to connect to it.

You're probably like me and 'vagrant halt' your box when you're done coding to free up resources and expect to just be able to turn it back on effortlessly with 'vagrant up', but it would seem that's not the case. Hopefully this gets you back on your feet and someone else who knows whats happening can explain why this happens.

Comment: My box ended up locked because my computer froze while vagrant was running (under-powered laptop) and I had to manually shut it down. `vagrant reload` got the vm running again.

Comment: Sadly, this solution didn't work for me. To fix it, I had to restart my computer. If you are using windows and fast startup is enabled, you may want to **restart** rather than turning the computer off and on again.

Answer (score 10):

On Windows, I killed my Ruby processes and then was able to successfully run 'vagrant halt' and then 'vagrant up'.

Comment: this helped me as well :)

Comment: This helped... even `vagrant status` complained about the lock until I did this.

Comment: Yup..this works.

Answer (score 9):

Just lost an hour to this problem.  My final solution:

1. Delete the machine from Virtualbox
2. Delete the `.vagrant` folder (if present) in the directory containing your Vagrantfile
3. If you still get the error (as I did), run `vagrant global-status` to check for any still-recognized machines
4. If the machine is still listed, run `vagrant global-status --prune` to remove it
5. `vagrant up` should work again

Comment: This worked for me, but steps 4 and 5 gave me errors until I restarted Windows.

Answer (score 2):

On windows, with "tasklist" find the process id of your "vagrant.exe" and "ruby.exe".

Now kill both the processes with "taskkill /PID <PID> /F" command. You are ready to go.

Run "vagrant up".

That should do.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOSX, I went to Activity Monitor and just killed the vagrant process that was running. That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my PC fixed the error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this by resume the vm in vm app.